# How does spring security pass credentials? / Postman

Tags: spring, spring-security, postman

I just created a basic layer to secure my Spring API.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

    List<UserDetails> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("Admin").password("xxx!!").roles("ADMIN").build());
    users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("Pharmacist").password("xxx!!").roles("PHARMACIST").build());
    users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("Office").password("xxx!!").roles("OFFICE").build());

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
}
}
```

I am using Postman to test my endpoints and it's working via the Authorization function of Postman.

What if I want to use this parameters (username,password,role) in my frontend?

I mean, that I am trying somehow to see how spring security passes the values to the url: http://localhost:8080 but i cant find out how. I need this to be able to handle in my Frontend with these vaules.

I am really new in this Spring Security Chapter.

Comment: this guide will get you started on https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: i already got trough this tutorial but it is not answering my Question.
I want to find out how to pass the data to my angular frontend (username, password, role)

Comment: Am not front-end expert, but quick googling gave me another guide: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: I think you want your own user table and implement a custom UserDetailsService against this user table in your own database. Then you're able to return for example all users (and use them in an admin panel?!). If you just want to retrieve the information about the current user check out this. https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security